# VBA Get Row and Column Index of Cell Clicked to Open UserBox in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a UserBox which opens on the double click of cells within a specified range. I do this with simple intersection checking in `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick()`. I have a row of header tags in my sheet and I want a label within the opened UserBox to display "Opened with X" where X is the header of the column the cell is in. For example, if cell C9 is double clicked, I want to to display the text of the header located in cell C2. I know how to apply the contents of an arbitrary cell to a label within the UserBox, but I'm not sure how to extract the row and column of the cell that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Column As Long, Row As Long

    Column = Target.Column
    Row = Target.Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I can simply call `ActiveCell.Row` and `ActiveCell.Column`.

Comment: try to avoid `ActiveCell`, `Select` etc because they cause confusion.